Confusion about acceleration when pulling a massively long object in space
I have this thought experiment that I just don't manage to solve. I'm sure there have been similar questions and answers, yet I haven't found any that explained it to me.
I have no particular physics education apart from high school-level newtonian physics, so the mathy answers do not clarify the problem for me, and I feel like I have important flaws in the way I think movement and forces work, so please correct me on those.
Suppose you are floating in deep space, and in front of you is a very, very long object. Say a string, a long bar, whatever. The object is millions of kilometers long and so is very massive.
Next to it is a very small piece of string.
If I pull on the small string, I will experience a very small displacement, while the string will move towards me.
But if I pull the big string, I don't know what to expect. My intuition is that surely you should experience much more acceleration than the string, since it's so much massive than you. But since it's so big, the "information" of the mass shouldn't travel instantaneously from one end to the other, so how is the acceleration you experience actually determined ?
I have gained lots of insight from this article cited in another answer: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SpeedOfLight/FTL.html#3
see point 4: rigid bodies
But couldn't predict what would happen to the person pulling/pushing the object.
Please do point out if there is need for simplification/correction, as English is not my main language and I could be too lengthy or have bad grammar.

If there is just you and the object in deep space, then the motion of the centre of mass of the combined system of you and the object is not affected by your pull (with regards to the combined system of you and the object, your pull is an internal force). So we can make life simpler for ourselves if we work in a reference frame in which this combined centre of mass is stationary.
Your pull brings you and the object closer together, but the rate at which this happens is determined by two things: (1) the strength of your muscles and (2) the mass of the object.
If the object is very light compared to you then even a small pull accelerates in quickly. Because you are hardly using your muscles the object "feels" light and it "feels" as if you are pulling the object towards you. In the combined centre of mass reference frame the object moves much more quickly than you do.
If the object is very massive compared to you then even pulling with your full strength hardly accelerates it at all. Because you are using your full strength the object "feels" heavy and it "feels" as if you are pulling yourself towards the object. In the combined centre of mass reference frame the object moves much more slowly than you do.
With a massive and large object then there will be some deformation of the object as the force that you are exerting on it propagates through the object. If the object is solid, like a metal bar, then the speed at which this deformation moves through the object is limited by the speed of sound in that object. However, most large solid objects are so stiff that the deformation caused by your muscle strength will be negligible - for all practical purposes, the object can be treated as if it were a rigid body. Incidentally, this is mostly true because the materials out of which we build massive objects on Earth must be at least strong enough to support their own weight - it would be very difficult to build a skyscraper out of jelly and custard. As a result, when climbing a climbing wall for example, we do not worry that we might bend the whole building.
However, if you are pulling a large spring or rubber band (or a massive jelly), then the deformation of the object and the rate at which this deformation propagates through the object may become important. Similarly, if large forces are involved - such as powerful rocket engines - then even the strongest materials can no longer be treated as rigid. And once you start to consider objects that are "millions of kilometers long" then their own gravitational attraction becomes important - this will tend to pull the object into a sphere.

thank you for your answer. I understand that for practicality the rigid body approximation is enough, however I am looking for the "quantum" explanation. In newtonian physics you say "the acceleration is a function of your strength and the mass of the object" but if the object is millions of kilometers long, surely you'd have to account for the speed of sound/light in the object to get the result ?

@Sreckcep An object that big is effectively both rigid and immovable. You do not worry about moving or deforming the Earth every time you walk down the street.

...Sure ? I don't really know what you're responding to, but my question was specifically about a certain thought experiment and understanding the inner workings of physics... I don't really know if whether I should worry about it or not is that relevant

@Sreckcep What I mean is that we can calculate your motion walking down the street without having to consider whether the Earth moves while you are doing so - even though we know it does move very slightly. A large part of "the inner workings of physics" is knowing which factors are significant and which can be ignored and how to tell the difference. If we tried to model the motion of every individual atom in order to determine the motion of macroscopic objects then physics would not get anywhere.

When I was in high school, my physics teacher used to use a mouse and an elephant for these kinds of questions. What happens if you push on a mouse? What happens if you push on an elephant?
First Newton's Laws. The $3^{rd}$ law is commonly stated as "For every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction." Forces always come in equal and opposite pairs. If you push on an elephant, you don't just push on the elephant. The elephant also pushes on you.
You push yourselves apart. The same thing happens if you push on a mouse, but there is a difference. You need Newton's $2^{nd}$ law: $F = ma$.
Forces cause objects to accelerate, to change their speed. A mouse has a small mass. An elephant has a big mass. If you apply the same force to both, the mouse has a bigger acceleration.
$$m_{mouse}a_{mouse} = F = m_{elephant}a_{elephant}$$
or
$$a_{mouse} = \frac{m_{elephant}}{m_{mouse}}a_{elephant}$$
In both cases, you experience the same reaction force, and have the same acceleration. If you pushed on both for the same amount of time and then stopped, you would arrive at the same speed.

Thank you for your answer. So what you mean is, the acceleration of the person pushing the object is independant of the mass of the object ? And it is just that we can more easily exert force on a massive object ?

The force on you is the same as the force you exert. It might be easier to push hard on an elephant because a mouse gets pushed out of reach before you are up to full strength. But that is just a matter of how you push. Yes. How hard you decide to push on something one thing. The mass of what you push on is another.
